# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error comes while accessing all public facing websites like google, bing from my laptop

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority

ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error comes while accessing all public facing websites like google, bing from my laptop.

I was getting ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID earlier and deleted certificates which are expired. Now, INVALID is coming.

Issuer: SSL-SG1-GLOBAL

Please help on this.

I tried changing Date settings in my  machine.
I have deleted expired GLOBALSIGN certificates
And installed more certificates from GLOBALSIGN site but issue not resolved